# jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget:-after submitting button(after postback) only last selected element is checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am implementing this JQuery UI multiselect from http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

I have managed to get it to use in my asp.net page, but while i am submitting the button, the selected text shows only the last element checked. So how to maintain all the checked items `after post back`.Can anyone help me?

Here i am populating the data in to dropdownlist and the main functionality is written on DAL to get the data from database.

```
protected void ClearNPouplateListBox(DropDownList ctrl, DataTable dt)
    {
        try
        {
            ctrl.DataSource = dt;
            ctrl.DataTextField = "Name";
            ctrl.DataValueField = "Id";
            ctrl.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Write("Exception in LogGeneralIncidentForm.ClearNPouplateListBox Method" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here I am trying to keep the selected items in data table

```
DataTable dtAssigners = new DataTable();
            dtAssigners.Columns.Add("GIMID", typeof(int));
            dtAssigners.Columns.Add("UserId", typeof(int));
            dtAssigners.Columns.Add("MODE", typeof(char));
            dtAssigners.Columns.Add("CreatedBy", typeof(int));
            DataTable dt = null;

            foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem list in ddlAssignedTo.Items)
            {

                if (list.Selected)
                {

                    DataRow drUsers = dtAssigners.NewRow();
                    drUsers["GIMID"] = GIMID;
                    drUsers["MODE"] = 'I';
                    drUsers["UserId"] = Convert.ToInt32(list.Value);
                    drUsers["CreatedBy"] = CurUsr.UserId;
                    dtAssigners.Rows.Add(drUsers);
                }
          }
```

My java script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        /*
        define global variable,
        and store message container element.
        */
        var warning = $(".message");

        $("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlAssignedTo").multiselect(
        {
            selectedList: 10,

            show: ["slide", 1000],

            hide: ["slide", 1000],

            header: "Choose only TEN items!",

            click: function (e) {

                if ($("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlAssignedTo").multiselect("widget").find("input:checked").length > 10) {
                    warning.addClass("error").removeClass("success").html("You can only check ten checkboxes!");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    warning.addClass("success").removeClass("error").html("Check a few boxes.");
              }    

            }

        }).multiselectfilter();

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using a listbox control make sure you include the SelectionMode attribute and set it to multiple. I just ran into this issue and it corrected it for me. Below I attached my exact code snippet.

aspx page:

```
<td><asp:ListBox ID="ddlRegion" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" /></td>
<td><asp:ListBox ID="ddlZone" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" /></td>
<td><asp:ListBox ID="ddlDistrict" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" /></td>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#<%=ddlRegion.ClientID%>').multiselect({
  noneSelectedText: "Select Region",
  header: false
});
$('#<%=ddlZone.ClientID%>').multiselect({
  noneSelectedText: "Select Zone",
  header: false
});
$('#<%=ddlDistrict.ClientID%>').multiselect({
  noneSelectedText: "Select District",
  header: false
});
```

No server-side code was needed for me to keep values on post back

Answer (score 0):

After Post back You Have to Bind Dropdwon again And Set Selected="Selected" Attribute for Selected Item in dropdown

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="foo" selected="selected" >foo</option>
  <option value="bar" selected="selected" >bar</option>
  <option value="baz" selected="selected">baz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But my drop-down list is taking data from database at run time..so where should i bind drop-down again?

Comment: After Data bind you have to Add Attribute in Your Dropdown using for loop

Comment: Code is follow <br/> For Each it As ListItem In ddlas.Items
            it.Attributes.Add("selected", "selected")
        Next

Comment: In Submit button u have called ClearNPouplateListBox Funtion to populate dropdwon after that u hv to check if dropdwon value is exist in dtAssigners that Add Attribute to dropdown

Comment: @ anil shah ..no its nt working..  while m clicking on the submitting button its loosing its multiselect property..only last item is get selected..i thnk der ll be some changes in jquery..

Comment: u can not get direct selected item from multi selected dropdwon u have to take hdnfield to store selected value of dropdown and then acess that value in postback of submit button

Comment: write one javascript validation function on submit button and assign hdn field value. code as follow: var va =$('#ddlas').val().join(',')
                        $('#hdn').val(va);

Comment: then acess that value in codebehind file using split function

Comment: yes..anil i hv already assigned in hidden field.But how to store dat hidden field value in data table i.e dtAssigners(see the above code i mentioned)...

Comment: Change your Foreach Statement using this  ==>                       string[] value = "asd,asd".ToString().Split(",");

foreach (string va in value) {                                  DataRow drUsers = dtAssigners.NewRow();
                    drUsers["GIMID"] = GIMID;
                    drUsers["MODE"] = 'I';
                    drUsers["UserId"] = Convert.ToInt32(va);
                    drUsers["CreatedBy"] = CurUsr.UserId;
                    dtAssigners.Rows.Add(drUsers);
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47725/discussion-between-anil-shah-and-madhu)